# Checking if a date and time are more than x hours in the past

Tags: mysql, date

I have a table which has a single date column and then a time in and time out column - in some scenarios, it is possible that the time I am needing to check is yesterday and this is where I am struggling.

I can't change the table layout to use date times as this is part of a wider system which I am doing a small amount of work on.

For example, now it is 2019-02-21 20:01:00 and I am looking for all records which have a time in of more than 8 hours ago.

This is the query I am using:

```
SELECT id from table where
    ((date='2019-02-21' and time_in < date_sub(now(),interval 8 hour)) 
or 
    (date='2019-02-20' and time_in < date_add(now(), interval 16 hour))) 
and 
    time_out='00:00:00'
```

- If I have a date of 2019-02-21 and a time of 10:00 then this works
- If I have a date of 2019-02-20 and a time of 10:00 then this works
- If I have a date of 2019-02-21 and a time of 23:00 then this does NOT work

Is it possible to get this working with the scenario where the time plus the negative of the interval takes it over midnight/00:00?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`TIMESTAMP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestamp) function to combine date and time, then compare with dates:

```
WHERE TIMESTAMP(date, time_in) < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 8 HOUR
```